# C#: Porque no se suman en un total?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, string, visual-studio-2017, textbox

Estoy intentando hacer una suma como la de excel (automática) en C#, pero el código hace que un numero digitado se sume por si mismo 10 veces (mostrado en el total), para solucionarlo intente dividir el resultado entre 10, pero tampoco podía ya que me decía que no se puede convertir un "float a un string".

Código:

```
wsNumeric20.EditValueChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        wsNumeric21.Text =
            (float.Parse(wsNumeric20.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric19.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric18.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric17.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric16.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric15.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric14.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric13.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric12.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric11.Text).ToString());
    }
    catch {}
};

wsNumeric19.EditValueChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        wsNumeric21.Text =
            (float.Parse(wsNumeric20.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric19.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric18.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric17.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric16.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric15.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric14.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric13.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric12.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric11.Text).ToString());
    }
    catch { }
};

wsNumeric18.EditValueChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        wsNumeric21.Text =
            (float.Parse(wsNumeric20.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric19.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric18.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric17.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric16.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric15.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric14.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric13.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric12.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric11.Text).ToString());
    }
    catch { }
};

wsNumeric17.EditValueChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        wsNumeric21.Text =
            (float.Parse(wsNumeric20.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric19.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric18.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric17.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric16.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric15.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric14.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric13.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric12.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric11.Text).ToString());
    }
    catch { }
};

wsNumeric16.EditValueChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        wsNumeric21.Text =
            (float.Parse(wsNumeric20.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric19.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric18.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric17.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric16.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric15.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric14.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric13.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric12.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric11.Text).ToString());
    }
    catch { }
};

wsNumeric15.EditValueChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        wsNumeric21.Text =
            (float.Parse(wsNumeric20.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric19.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric18.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric17.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric16.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric15.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric14.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric13.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric12.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric11.Text).ToString());
    }
    catch { }
};

wsNumeric14.EditValueChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        wsNumeric21.Text =
            (float.Parse(wsNumeric20.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric19.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric18.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric17.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric16.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric15.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric14.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric13.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric12.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric11.Text).ToString());
    }
    catch { }
};

wsNumeric13.EditValueChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        wsNumeric21.Text =
            (float.Parse(wsNumeric20.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric19.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric18.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric17.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric16.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric15.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric14.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric13.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric12.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric11.Text).ToString());
    }
    catch { }
};

wsNumeric12.EditValueChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        wsNumeric21.Text =
            (float.Parse(wsNumeric20.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric19.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric18.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric17.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric16.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric15.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric14.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric13.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric12.Text) +
                float.Parse(wsNumeric11.Text).ToString());
    }
    catch { }
};

wsNumeric11.EditValueChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        wsNumeric21.Text =
            (float.Parse(wsNumeric20.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric19.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric18.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric17.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric16.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric15.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric14.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric13.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric12.Text) +
            float.Parse(wsNumeric11.Text).ToString());
    }
    catch { }
};
```

Pero al momento de ejecutarse ocurre esto (Ver imagen).

> (PD: el 5 * el 2000 quiero que se sumen todas las multiplicaciones), se que fácilmente puedo hacerlo agregando un botón y etc... pero lo quiero hacer sin botones ni eventos:

[image: Se suma diez veces..?]

Answer (score 1):

Lo pongo como respuesta para que sea vea mejor el codigo.

El problema es que en todos tus eventos, en la suma de los text Parseados a Float, en el ultimo termino lo pasas a String antes de completar la suma.

Aqui

...

```
float.Parse(wsNumeric11.Text).ToString());
```

Osea, concatena tu resultado numerico a "0,00"(string)

Puedes poner un paréntesis antes de convertirlo para que quede como calculo, y luego se convierta a string.
...

```
float.Parse(wsNumeric11.Text)).ToString();
```